# Crontab with python and venv

Tags: python, bash, cron, python-venv

I got a basic cron job working
`* * * * * echo "something" > /Users/sam/Desktop/crontest.txt`

But now I'm trying to get my python script that uses venv to work and still cant get it after trying several of the answers here to previous questions.

Main 2 I've tried, with syntax variations:

1. Bash script of

```
#!/bin/bash    
source /Users/sam/Desktop/python/venv/bin/activate
python /Users/sam/Desktop/python/py_files/script.py
```

with crontab:
`27 8 * * * bash /Users/sam/Desktop/python/venv_wrapper.sh`

2. All in cron

`27 8 * * * /Users/sam/Desktop/python/venv/bin/python /Users/sam/Desktop/python/py_files/script.py`

Comment: Option 2 seems better. Is there any error in cron logs ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer i havent been able to get access to the cron logs. i tried adding 
> /tmp/cronlog.txt 2>&1
but that doesn't seem to create the log file.

Comment: Does cron wrok at all ? Whats your linux distribution ?

Comment: Cron works im using Mac terminal.  This worked `* * * * * echo "something" > /Users/sam/Desktop/vscode/crontest.txt`

Answer (score 0):

At work I had the same issue and found out from another similar cron job that for this to work you must add a ". " to the begining of the command.
Not sure why but on this particular machine it only works this way.

> 27 8 * * * . /Users/sam/Desktop/python/venv/bin/python /Users/sam/Desktop/python/py_files/script.py

Comment: Did you check if cron is logging output to your user's email? Check it with mail or mail-x. Might help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: How do I check the logs I've been wanting to understand that.

Comment: On the machine where I was having the same issue as you cron logs to email messages to the user. So what I do is run  mail or mail-x and check on the logs. From cron's man page it looks like this is the default behavior and if you want to redirect the logs to syslog "-s"must be used.

Comment: hmm ok yes i found mail doing that thank you!! so they are all like this, not sure what to make of it: 

X-Original-To: sam
Delivered-To: sam@Sams-MacBook-Pro.local
From: sam@Sams-MacBook-Pro.local (Cron Daemon)
To: sam@Sams-MacBook-Pro.local
Subject: Cron <sam@Sams-MacBook-Pro> /Users/sam/Library/heptoic.hn/heptoic.hn cr
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=sam>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=sam>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/sam>
Date: Mon,  2 Nov 2020 07:20:01 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: /tmp/iu.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you open one of the emails? You can open them by typing the message number.

Comment: Yes its now showing an 'operation not permitted' error